# How to visualize java code using UML notations inside Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml

Is it possible to visualize the Java codes using UML notations inside Eclipse? Is there any pluggin available for Java?

Comment: UML Lab is commercial (http://www.uml-lab.com/en/uml-lab/)

Comment: Borland Together also have these features. http://www.borland.com/products/together/

Answer (score 1):

[Soyatec eUML](http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/) is one. It does relatively good round-trip engineering. It's commercial 'though, however with a relaxed license (i.e. the basic edition is free for most commercial projects - but do check the legal text to see if you comply) .

Also, note that it adds additional files into your projects (GMF files mostly), as well as custom annotations to your code. But it does do a reasonably good job.

Answer (score 1):

[Omondo](http://www.omondo.com/) is doing that. I have used a previous version and it worked fine. It is an eclipse plugin that uses annotations in order to synchronize java code and UML diagrams. It is commercial as well.

Comment: I've also looked at it, and now I remember why I didn't use it: they still don't have a Juno build.

Answer (score 0):

[Borland Together](http://www.borland.com/products/together/) is able to generate the UML diagram from your code. 
It also able to generate code based on your UML Diagram.

It is commercial though.

Was using this IDE around 5 years ago and quite impressed about it.